# SQL Developer - Accessing A Table in Another Connection

Tags: sql, oracle

I am learning about creating users, permissions and roles in Oracle. I have logged into a DB as an admin and created a user:

```
 CREATE USER U1
 IDENTIFIED BY A_password 
 DEFAULT TABLESPACE Users
 QUOTA 30M on Users
 PROFILE TestProfile  
 PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

Then I created a table called User1Table and threw some data in it:

```
CREATE TABLE USER1DATA 
(
  UID1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(40), 
  LASTNAME VARCHAR2(40),
  AGE NUMBER(3)
  );
```

I granted the user (U1) some permissions to connect to the DB, create a table, and view and insert into the User1Table:

```
Grant CREATE TABLE to U1;
Grant CREATE SESSION to U1;
Grant READ, INSERT ON USER1TABLE TO U1;
```

I changed the expired password on the user and established a connection to the database as the user but when I try to query the table from the user's connection with:

`SELECT * FROM USER1TABLE;`

I get the error message ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist. Is there step that I am missing? The database is the same. The only difference is I am connected as an established user instead of admin.

Answer (score 1):

If you did *exactly* the following as you posted

```
CREATE USER U1
 IDENTIFIED BY A_password 
 DEFAULT TABLESPACE Users
 QUOTA 30M on Users
 PROFILE TestProfile  
 PASSWORD EXPIRE;

CREATE TABLE USER1DATA 
(
  UID1 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
  FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(40), 
  LASTNAME VARCHAR2(40),
  AGE NUMBER(3)
  );
```

then you have created a user, but created the table in your ***current*** schema (your admin account).  This would ne why you cannot see it as U1 just by referencing "USER1DATA".  You would need to do

```
select * from ADMIN.USER1DATA
```

because it is your ADMIN account that owns the table.  To avoid the need for that you could do:

```
create synonym USER1DATA for ADMIN.USER1DATA
```

whilst connected as U1, or if you are connected as ADMIN you would do

```
create synonym U1.USER1DATA for USER1DATA
```